# Сделать бесплатную доставку образцов Magento

Tags: magento

Есть сайт на Magento, если в заказе только образцы чтобы била бесплатная доставка.
Пробовал создать правило акции но не нашел подходящего атрибута.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добаить атрибут к товарам например `example` при этом включив для него `разрешить использовать в promo rules` после чего создать правило для корзины вот [тут](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-free-shipping.html) подробнее и все будет ок.